# Using GifAnimation to load gifs

Tags: animation, reference, xna

I'm trying to load some gifs to my porjects, and I found a library that does that.
http://xnagif.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

I tried to add reference to it in my project, but when I try to create an instance of the GifAnimation class it gives me an error : 
GifAnimation is a 'namespace' but is used as a 'type'
Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show where/how you are using  GifAnimation in your code?

Comment: Can you tell me how it should be done since in my way there is obviously mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, I suspect this might be because you are trying to create an instance of the namespace rather than the class. Try

```
= new GifAnimation.GifAnimation();
```

The namespace and class have the same name (which is rather confusing).

Comment: what should be at the left of the  = . i tried GifAnimation a = new GifAnimation.GifAnimation(); but still the same problem

Comment: Thank you. it reconized the class. but now it says : "cannot aoutdetect which importer to use for the gif file